# chrome back button issue

Tags: google-chrome, button, back

in my website i am having a list box and by selecting it i am redirected to a result page, and when i click back button in browser the values staying there in Chrome ( IE and Firefox working fine,

any help??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do some value reset with javascript/jquery when page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old bug in chrome.

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2801

This bug cannot be fixed because chrome uses curl library to do redirect or something. I guess, use firefox to access those type of website.

Otherwise, ctrl+click-link on search page so that new page opens in a new window, and you don't lose the old page.